# Firestore: Multiple 'array-contains'

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Update on this question**

Firestore launched another feature similar to the in query, the array-contains-any query. This feature allows you to perform array-contains queries against multiple values at the same time.

Use the array-contains-any operator to combine up to 10 array-contains clauses on the same field with a logical OR. An array-contains-any query returns documents where the given field is an array that contains one or more of the comparison values:

`ref = ref.where('node_sku' , 'array-contains-any' , list);`

[Firestore - Array contains any](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any)

**Question**

I am trying to filter data with multiple `where()` methods using the `array-contains` operator, however I am having the following error:

```
An error occured: Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: 
A maximum of 1 'ARRAY_CONTAINS' filter is allowed.
```

Basically, I have a collection containing the following docs:

```
product1 
  - node_sku ['sku1', 'sku2', 'sku3' ]

product2 
  - node_sku ['sku4', 'sku5', 'sku6' ]
```

Then I have my array with items I wish to find on the database:

```
const list = ['sku4', 'sku2']
```

I want to search for `sku4` and `sku2`, if finds any returns the object.

My problem is that `array-contains` is not allowed to run more than once.

Here's the code I am using to filter:

```
const list = ['sku4', 'sku2'];


let database = firestore_db.collection('glasses');
let ref = database;

list.forEach( (val) => { 
    ref = ref.where('node_sku' , 'array-contains' , val);
});
ref.get() 
.then( (snapshot) => glassesRequestComplete(snapshot, req, response))
.catch( (error) => glassesRequestError(error, response) );
```

As you notice, my problem is that I am looping through my `list` array, however my `ref` is throwing an error since I am firing 'array-contains' more than once.

I have also tried to compare against the array:

```
ref.where('node_sku' , 'array-contains' , list);
```

which does not return any , I believe array-contains does not compare against arrays, only strings/numbers/booleans maybe?

Does anybody know a solution for that without having to query them individually?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firestore launched another feature similar to the in query, the array-contains-any query. This feature allows you to perform array-contains queries against multiple values at the same time.

```
ref = ref.where('node_sku' , 'array-contains-any' , list);
```

[Firestore - Array contains any](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any)

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I've updated my question based on your link and comments.

Comment: i think that solve the problem : val citiesRef = db.collection("cities")

citiesRef.whereIn("country", listOf("USA", "Japan"))

Comment: what if i want to find users that contain ONLY item1 AND item2? array contains will get all that contain EITHER 1 OR 2 right?

Answer (score 33):

One solution would be to store the 'tags' in an Object as its property names.

```
node_sku = {
  "sku1": true,
  "sku2": true,
  ...
  "skun": true
}
```

Then you can create the AND WHERE clauses like this:

```
list.forEach( (val) => { 
  ref = ref.where(`node_sku.${val}` , '==' , true);
});
```

This approach is an answer to the question "without having to query them individually". However, as soon as you want ordering and pagination, you will run into another invisible brick wall of compound indices.

Answer (score 14):

As you've found you can only have a single `array-contains` operation in a query. The idea of allowing multiple is currently not supported, but could be valid. So I recommend you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

The only solution I can think of for your use-case right now, is to also include the combinations. So if you want to allow testing for the existing of two SKUs, you explode the array to also contain each combination (merging keys in lexicographical order):

```
product1 
  - node_sku ['sku1', 'sku2', 'sku3', 'sku1_sku2', 'sku1_sku3', 'sku2_sku3' ]
```

For two that might still be reasonable, but the combinatory explosion will make it infeasible beyond that.

Comment: My problem is that I have thousands of sku's, which will make impossible for me to create that since all the combinations would be just too long. I feel like every time I come with an issue with Firebase is like hitting a wall with my head.  I'll make a request to them. You helpful as always! Thanks Frank

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to pull back all the items using 'array-contains-any', then use lodash _.intersection() to find the items that match all the terms.  It works for single term searching as well.

```
      const searchTerms = searchKey.split(" ");
      const searchTermCount = searchTerms.length;
      const productsRef = collection(this.db, "products");
      const termsQuery = query(productsRef,
            where("search", "array-contains-any", searchTerms),
            orderBy("popularity", "desc"),
            orderBy("name_lower"),
            limit(resultLimit));

        const snaps = await getDocs(termsQuery);   
        let products = [];
             
        snaps.forEach((doc) => {
          const p = doc.data();
          const allTerms = _.intersection(p.search, searchTerms).length === searchTermCount;
          if (allTerms)
            products.push(p);
      });
```

Comment: Not sure why I got downvoted.  The 'array-contains-any' returns the OR results.  My post-processing converts the result into an AND.  If you search for ['sku4, 'sku2'], firebase will give you back results that have either.  My post-process filters that down to only results with both.

Comment: Edit your answer if including additional or clarifying information, don't add as a comment.

Answer (score -2):

Use something like this :

```js
ref.where("node_sku", "in", list).get()
.then((snapshot) => glassesRequestComplete(snapshot, req, response)).catch( (error) => glassesRequestError(error, response) );
```