# How to fetch documents from Firebase cloud firestore with whereValueInArray condition

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get posts from a particular group of users.

So I need a query like this:

```
postCollectionRef.whereValueInArray("by_uid", userList).get();
```

Basically only getting posts which have the field "by_uid" in userList. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add more code and examples? Like you can start with sharing your current schema

Comment: There is no support for specifying multiple values in a `whereValueInArray`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837711/firestore-multiple-array-contains

Comment: I believe you are asking how to perform an OR query; retrieve posts from user 0 or user 1 or user 2... There are a number of questions very similar to this with a variety of answers [Firestore OR Query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirestore%5Dor+query) so I am marking as duplicate..