# Got Cornered in a multiple "array-in" query (nuxt, @nuxtjs/firebase)

Tags: typescript, firebase, nuxt.js, vuefire

> **Note**  A POC is included below

> **Note** I have checked this question: [Firebase Firestore - Filter data with multiple 'array-contains'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56544447/firebase-firestore-filter-data-with-multiple-array-contains)

#### Project Stack:

- Nuxt@2.15.8
- @nuxtjs/firebase

#### Overview of the issue/question:

In a Firebase document, we have 2 attributes with `<Array>` type

```
const Pitch = {
  // ...
  formats: [],
  themes: []
}
```

When trying to filter pitch documents based on both fields, we get trapped in a corner where there is a Firebase caveat in Compound queries `FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Invalid query. You cannot use more than one 'array-contains' filter`

#### Actual POC

The following sandbox illustrates the actual complex component: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-8dqt1c?file=README.md

#### Question

What's the best workaround to get the filtration scenario easier as a development experience?

Comment: Well, I think you can merge the formats and themes into one array. (Or you can add a separate array for that) and store the values like : `format__theme` and query it like `acc.where('format_theme', 'array-contains','format1__theme2' )`

Comment: @Eldar, I will consider that approach, thank you :)

Comment: Actually `formats` is an `string[]`, however, `themes` is an `object[]`.