# Flutter Firebase ArrayContains Query in For Loop

Tags: firebase, flutter, for-loop, google-cloud-firestore, where-clause

```
String squery;

var sRef = _firestore
          .collection("vehicles1")
          .where("models", arrayContains: squery);
```

With this code i can display lists which include squery variable.

If I use this code in a for loop like this way;

```
List<String> item = ["motor", "car", "plane"];

var sRef;

for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
      sRef = _firestore
          .collection("vehicles1")
          .where("models", arrayContains: item[i]);
    }
```

I can display lists containing elements in the item list. But I am facing a problem here. When I want to use the for loop to display the lists containing the elements in the item list, the code additionally shows me the lists containing the last element in the item list.

For example, in this example, it shows me the lists that include motor, car, and plane, and it also shows lists that contain only plane, but I don't want to display only the lists that contain plane, I just want to display the lists that contain motor, car, plane.

So I just want to display All Doc list in my Firebase Documents.

And these are my Firebase Documents.

[Motor Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G85Ix.png)

[Car Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV1dV.png)

[Plane Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoSEm.png)

[All Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TSyU.png)

When I run the code with for loop that I wrote above, I get an output like this, but I just want to get the list named ALL.

[My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOMem.png)

Why I get list named PLANE with list named ALL. I just want get to list named ALL.

Answer (score 0):

In every iteration of the `for` loop you are overwriting the `sRef` variable, and checking that the `models` array contains one specific element of the `item` list. Therefore, in the last iteration, you are retrieving the arrays that contain the `plane` item, this is `PLANE` and `ALL`.

What you are trying is an `array-contains-all` like operation, which is not currently supported. You can check [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59135592/firestore-array-contains-query-for-list-of-elements) for more information on this topic.

Comment: This problem is for flutter firebase, I think it's a big shortcoming. While there are features like array contains and array contains any, there should be an absolute use of array contains all, by the way thank you for your answer.

Comment: So, do you think there is a way to somehow fix the plane part, which is the last stage of this for loop?

Comment: One option is to store the `models` data as a `map` structure instead of as an `array`, i.e. `{motor: true, plane: true, car: true}` so you will be able to filter like: ```_firestore.collection("vehicles1").whereField("models.plane", isEqualTo: true).whereField("models.car", isEqualTo: true).whereField("models.motor", isEqualTo: true)```

Comment: Well, can I do this query in the for loop because I will query the elements in the list and their elements and numbers will be variable.

Comment: I think there is not a simple way to go through it. One option might be to iterate over all the documents in `vehicles1`, from each document retrieve the `models` array and check outside firestore if that array contains all the elements that you want (all the elements in the `item` array, in this case). If it does, retrieve that document, if not, continue with the next document.

Comment: I know I asked a lot of questions, but for this if else condition, can you give an example adapted to my example?

Comment: I have to somehow do the array-contains-all operation. There has to be a way.

Comment: @Rkdio , pardon but do you wish to do this array-contains-all operation using firestore or using dart(flutter)? I think there might be a way to do this using dart (through a combination of the `where` filter and using the `intersect` method compared to what you're intersecting with), however Firestore's query's are rather limited, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations), so I don't think that's currently possible within Firestore.