# Can I use IN on Firestore Database to check if an array is covered by another array?

Tags: arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

- "ingredients1":["banana","apple", "milk"]
- "ingredients2":["orange","apple", "water"]
- "ingredients3":["banana","kiwi", "milk"]
- "inventory":["banana","kiwi","milk","apple"]

Hello, these are the arrays I need to work on and need to find a way to check which ingredients arrays are covered by inventory array.

The query builder looks like that:
https://ibb.co/gTMcbL6

Thanks ahead.

I tried this query and it returned null but I was expecting to see the ingredient arrays which are covered by the inventory array.

Comment: What do you mean by "covered by the inventory array"? Please provide an example of a query and the expected result.

Comment: Assuming ingredients are required to make desserts and the inventory is the ingredients I have. I need to get the list of the desserts I can make with the ingredients I have.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for multiple ingredients that would require an `array-contains-all` operation, which does not currently exist on Firestore.

A workaround would be to store the ingredients as a map, instead of as an array. So something like:

```
ingredients-map: {
  banana: true,
  apple: true, 
  milk: true
}
```

With that maps, and the right indexes on it, you can then perform a query with multiple equality checks to find the recipes with all the right ingredients.

Also see:

- [Firestore array contains query for list of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59135592/firestore-array-contains-query-for-list-of-elements/59142459#59142459)
- [Firestore search array contains for multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987399/firestore-search-array-contains-for-multiple-values)
- [Firestore: Multiple 'array-contains'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837711/firestore-multiple-array-contains)
- [Firestore query - array contains all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63852721/firestore-query-array-contains-all)
- [Firebase Flutter - Request with multiple where arrayContains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75117592/firebase-flutter-request-with-multiple-where-arraycontains/75119351#75119351)

Comment: I cant understand the query format here. With this structure would I not need to query with ingredient-map.banana == true and so on? Can I use the IN function with maps? Because I will need to search for example 1000 recipes to see which desserts I can make with the ingredients I have. As I understand array_contains function checks if the array in my document has the value/s I query and nothing more but I need the vice versa(if the array/map is covered by the array/map on the right side)

Comment: "With this structure would I not need to query with ingredient-map.banana == true and so on?" Yes. --- "Can I use the IN function with maps?" No. --- I recommend giving this data model a try based on what I explained and the questions I linked (many of which contain code samples). If you can't get it to work, post back with your updated data model, the code that you tried, and the output/error you got.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that, thanks for now and in advance.