# How dynamic add an array of functions to an javascript function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I do have this structure:

```
db.collection('users')
```

and want to make this:

```
db.collection('users')
   .where('works', 'array-contains', 'CASE_A')
   .where('works', 'array-contains', 'CASE_B')
   .where('works', 'array-contains', 'CASE_C')
   ...
```

In this case, I will make an array of
`(( .where('works', 'array-contains',`${variable}`))`

and i will add this in the beginning db.collection('users'), how can i make this?

Comment: I think you can use Javascript eval function and array join function.

Comment: If you want to write a query which contains ALL the cases, you will have to create a separate query for each case and merge the query results in your app. The following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-combined-two-firestore-queries-to-simulate-a-logical-or-query-27d28a43cb2d) explains how to do that (disclaimer, I'm the author).

Answer (score 2):

Just make an inline array:

```
db.collection('users')
   .where('works', 'array-contains', ['CASE_A', 'CASE_B', 'CASE_C'])
```

Or use a variable if you want:

```
const array = ['CASE_A', 'CASE_B', 'CASE_C']
db.collection('users')
   .where('works', 'array-contains', array)
```

If you actually want to find documents where **all** cases are present (not where **any** of the cases are present), you won't be able to use an array-contains type query.  You will have to convert your array into an object and query it as shown in this question: [Firestore: Multiple 'array-contains'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837711/firestore-multiple-array-contains)

Comment: will this return a query which contains ALL the cases ? I want the documents where all cases match.

Comment: No, this will do a logical OR of each item.  You can't do a logical AND of each item, as Firestore doesn't support multiple array-contains clauses in a single query.  If you want to use an object instead of an array, use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837711/firestore-multiple-array-contains

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.

```js
const makeItem = value => `.where('works', 'array-contains',${value}`

const arrFuncs = [
    makeItem('CASE_A'),
    makeItem('CASE_B'),
    makeItem('CASE_C'),
]

const initialCmd = `db.collection('users')`
eval(initialCmd + arrFuncs.join(''))
```